# DHCP в Kerio Control

Tags: dhcp, lan

Добрый день, поставил Kerio Control.
При конфигурировании DHCP сервера в Kerio, выбираю задать вручную,

> диапазон *.*.10.2 - *.*.10.254 , маска подсети 255.255.255.0

при этом статический адрес сетевой карты (локальная сеть) задан

> 192.168.10.1, маска подсети такая же.

Создаю аренду для хоста PC1 *.*.10.2, в результате компьютер PC1 вообще не получает IP адрес.

Но если в настройках DHCP сервера выбираю АВТОМАТИЧЕСКОЕ конфигурирования сервера то  диапазон почему-то задается

> от *.*.10.11 до *.*.10.254

и все работает PC1 нормально получает адрес.
Не пойму что делаю не так, мне нужен

> диапазон раздачи IP адресов 2 - 254  а не 11-254.

Кто знает подскажите, что не так! Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Может быть, проблема проще - адрес из статической аредны попросту не может входить в динамический диапазон?

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужен статический адресс для PC1 или без разницы?

Если без разницы - не добавляйте аренду.

Если нужна аренда - указывайте диапазон 3-254.

Если не нужен динамический диапазон - удалите его и задавайте арендой.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, нужна статика,  как я понял 10 адресов автоматически резервируются системой, по этому и при ручной настройке DHCP начинает нормально работать только в диапазоне с 10 по 254 адрес.